Does subjunctive mood reflects the speaker's estimate of the likelihood?
Example 1

John:She thinks if it rained on her birthday next week, she would not go out and celebrate her birthday at an open air restaurant. However, I think it is actually very likely to rain on her birthday. I have checked the weather forecast.

Example 2

John: She thinks if it rains on her birthday next week, she will not go out and celebrate her birthday at an open air restaurant. However, I think it is actually very likely to rain on her birthday. I have checked the weather forecast.

Does subjunctive mood reflects the speaker's estimate of the likelihood?
When John's belief doesn't align with what she believes, does he use the subjunctive mood in the reported clause said by her or not?

No. With 'She thinks', only (2) is correct.

I believe you mean subjunctive mood? Still, it’s not subjunctive, but conditional.

Banish the idea of subjunctive in these sentences. There is an if clause with a simple past and an if clause with the present.

It could be interpreted that way. But when John's belief doesn't align with what she believes, does he use the subjunctive mood in the reported clause or not?

It can, but not in that example.
But take for instance:

"If you are really Ilsa, you'll remember the time we shared in Paris." Maybe you are; I'm allowing the possibility.
"If you were really Ilsa, you'd remember the time we shared in Paris." You don't, so you're not.


A is the person's name. He himself does not believe it will rain. So I'm asking if it's  necessary to use subjunctive mood in the reported clause that is said by "she".

@vincentlin It’s “reported speech.” The if-clause is not Jon’s but hers.
